# JMeter: failed POST method (JSON body and filtering in path)

Tags: json, post, jmeter, access-token

I'm trying (without success) to create data in JMeter (**POST** method) using **JSON body** data and only one way of access through API: **access key** (no login credentials or other details for server).

The access key only works in PATH (tried in header, no luck) and besides that, **filters** are required in path to call the exact services I need (please see screenshot 1)

Here are a couple of screenshots (data was edited, sensitive info)

1
[HTTP Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GruBB.jpg)

2
[Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kB48.jpg)

In Results Tree I get 301 Moved Permanently.

Is there a way to add those filters, keep the JSON body data + access token in path and get a 200/201 Created? :)

Comment: One best way is to record those API's, using JSON path extractor you can grab what you want and post it in next request......

Comment: Yes, but for me this is not an efficient solution, let's say I'll have to POST 20 records/day (new data, you can't extract it with GET and you'll have to write it manually). If I store the variables with JSON Patch extractor it will be of no use when POSTing because I need unique data content for values in json.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue for "301 Moved Permanently" after Post method was used:
**Should have specified in Protocol "https" not http** :(